# How to automatically activate a TMP_InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I have two TMP_InputField in unity. I am trying to automatically focus on and activate the other once the first one has an input. I have tried the following but for some reasons, it's not working for me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FocusBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField b1;
    public TMP_InputField b2;
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (b1.isFocused)
        {
            if (b1.text.Length > 0)
            {
                b2.Select();
                b1.DeactivateInputField();
            }

        }
        Debug.Log("is b1 focused after : " + b1.isFocused);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly sure what exactly you mean with "has an input".

However, I think you could use the `OnValueChanged` event on your `TMP_InputField`. Either assign a Callback via the Inspector or overwrite it programatically. Everytime your input changes, your Callback will be triggered.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out actually, I was just wanted to finish up my work before posting the solution. OnValueChanged did the work.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked:) Good luck with your project!